# бекграунд на весь экран

Tags: html, css, frontend

есть макет, первая картинка на фул экран. я пишу этой картинке

```
    background: url(/img/top-bc__bicycle.svg)no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
```

но оно почему то обрезается внизу, как сделать ее на фул экран чтобы не обрезалась? как сохранить пиксель пёрфект
1) то что выходит    2)то что должно получиться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы растровую картинку запихнули в svg ?

Comment: @MaximLensky я поменял на jpg уже, я понял что svg только на иконок и логотипов

Comment: svg годится и для фона тоже, просто рисовать надо полноэкранное svg

Comment: @MaximLensky ну так как всё таки растянуть картинку без обрезания?

Comment: background-size: 100% 100% вроде так

Comment: @MaximLensky спасибо

Comment: помогло ?......

Comment: @MaximLensky да, но она теперь не масшатбируется при уменьшении экрана, а просто сжимается

Comment: другого не бывает ...contain ещё попробуйте

Comment: @MaximLensky вопрос тогда как делать лучше, адаптивно или не адаптивно, а пиксель пёрфект

Comment: а картинка не должна обрезаться, в зависимости от размера экрана? Если у нас ширина 100%, то высота уже как выйдет, в зависимости от размера картинки и экрана